# Connect a Bigquery function with Cloud functions

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, connection, credentials

I am trying to create a function in Bigquery which pulls a Cloud Functions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `DATASET.XXXXX`(user_id int64, corp_id STRING) RETURNS STRING
    REMOTE WITH CONNECTION `myPROJECTID.REGION.MY_CONNECTION`
        OPTIONS (
            endpoint = 'https://XXXX.cloudfunctions.net/XXXXX'
        )
```

previously create a connection in the Bigquery shell, but I get the following error, does anyone know?

```
Keyword REMOTE is not supported at [2:1]
```

or

```
Not found: Connection my-connection
```

Answer (score 1):

Your project must be allowlisted. It's a private preview (I asked 2 month ago, still nothing....)

[image]